# Chain functions using bluebird promises in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm sorry for asking yet another Promise question however, I can't quite grasp it and after reading tons of questions on here and explanations I'm still struggling.

So in my nodejs project, I'm trying to do three things.

*1)* Get user info from the Facebook API

```
graph.get(message.user, function getUserInfo(err, res) {
     console.log(res)
}
```

*2)* Get a list of users from another API

```
request.get('https://api-url/api/users', {
        'auth': {
            'bearer': 'bearerAuth'
        }
    })
```

*3)* Check the name from the Facebook user matches a name in the JSON data I get back from my API then hand it to the user.

```
let aPieceOfData = "";

Bluebird.promisifyAll(graph.get(message.user))
    .then(function(res) {
        // this should give me the response from the Facebook API which is the user
        // Then pass the response to the next .then(function(){})
    })
    .then(function(res) {
       request.get('https://api-url/api/users', {
         'auth': {
           'bearer': 'bearerAuth'
         }
         const apiData = JSON.parse(response.body);
         for (i in apiData) {
          if (res.username == apiData[i].username) {
            // if the username matches the user name then save some data to a variable outside this scope so I can access it
            aPieceOfData = apiData[i].item;
          }
         }
       })
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err, "<<<<<<<");
    })
```

Formatting might be a little off. But I'm struggling to understand how promises work and how I can pass the data between my chained functions than at the end save it outside my function so I can use it.

Can someone give a bit of explanation and/or some links to beginner friendlier explanations.

Comment: try like that `var g = Bluebird.promisifyAll(graph); g.get(message.user).then(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the example [from the doc](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html)

> ```
> var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"));
>
> fs.readFileAsync("myfile.js", "utf8").then(function(contents) {
>     console.log(contents); }).catch(function(e) {
>     console.error(e.stack); });
> ```

I believe it should be like this:

```
var g = Bluebird.promisifyAll(graph);
g.getAsync(message.user)
    .then(function (res) {
        // this should give me the response from the Facebook API which is the user
        // Then pass the response to the next .then(function(){})
        return res;
    })
    .then(function (res) {
        return request.get('https://api-url/api/users', {
            'auth': {
                'bearer': 'bearerAuth'
            }
        });
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        const apiData = JSON.parse(response.body);
        for (i in apiData) {
            if (res.username == apiData[i].username) {
                // if the username matches the user name then save some data to a variable outside this scope so I can access it
                aPieceOfData = apiData[i].item;
            }
        }
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err, "<<<<<<<");
    });
```

Comment: I get a `TypeError: g.get(...).then is not a function` I have included Bluebird above though like such... `const Bluebird        = require("bluebird")`

Comment: can you setup a plunker?

Comment: Nope :) I've been doing a bit of reading on promises to try and figure out what i'm missing. So the return statement on the request.get method is returning a promise not the value

Comment: So in my third `.then` i'm getting the value from `res` instead of from response

Comment: @SmurfEkko, sure, if it helped, you can upvote or accept the answer :). You can also update your question with details regarding _So in my third .then i'm getting the value from res instead of from response_

Comment: Will do! Thanks for the help! Once i've fixed my issue. I'll answer my own question with what I did to fix it but marked yours as accepted for helping since you put me in the right direction :)

Comment: _request.get method is returning a promise not the value_ - that is correct, it should return a promise. when a promise inside `then()` is returned, it substitutes the promise returned by the `then()`, and so essentially the third `.then` is chained to the promise returned by the `request.get`

Comment: Ahhh I see. That makes sense. Yeah so in my end `.then` where i'm console.logging out `response` I get back the request with info on the API request and the graph get request. But I don't actually get back the data from those requests

Comment: @SmurfEkko, can you post your relevant code in the quesiton?